# Check checkbox only prev one checked in dynamically created table

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Dynamically created table has one checkbox in each row. For first time if first check was check allow only next  `td checkbox` can be checked..
Second time prev checked checkbox will be automatically checked and disabled..find next to disabled td checkbox and allow next to check.

**table**

```
$('.medi_stps').append('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+b.steps+'</td><td class = "tim'+b.dt_id+'">'+'----'+'</td><td><input type = "checkbox"  class = "chk_val'+b.dt_id+' chk_val"  value = '+b.dt_id+'></td><td style = "display:none"><input  type = "text" disabled class = "checkboxval" name = "step_chkd[]"></td></tr>');                                           

    $(document).on('change','.chk_val',function () {
    var all_chkbxs = $('input.chk_val').length;
    var all_ckcked = $('input.chk_val:checked').length

      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        //$(".chk_val").attr("disabled", true);  
        $(".chk_val:lt("+ index +")").attr("disabled", false);

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            var sected_stp = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().parent().children().find('.checkboxval').val(sected_stp);
            $(this).parent().parent().children().find('.checkboxval').prop('disabled',false);
            var dest = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').prev().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().children().find('.checkboxval').val('');
                $(this).parent().parent().children().find('.checkboxval').prop('disabled',true);
        }
```

example:
There a 4 steps need to perform.
if checkbox 1 must be checked for first time and all other's must not.After checking 1 checkbox i will submit.When i click again to perform second step prev checked checkbox will be checked and disabled..allow only to select next checkbox..

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to get us to do your homework assignment.

Comment: @Rasclatt ..NO not at all. I was just trying it for a long time.